# Updating TextView on tick from other class?

Tags: java, android

I have a Fragment class, GameActivity_InfoPane, with a static function:

```
public static void updateGameTimeCount(int seconds) {
    gameTimeCount.setText(Integer.toString(seconds));
}
```

And then, i have this method in my GameController class, which calls the function to update the view in the fragment class:

```
public void runGameTimeCount(){
    handler = new Handler();
    handlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
        int seconds = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
                Log.d("gameActivity", Integer.toString(seconds));
                GameActivity_InfoPane.updateGameTimeCount(seconds);
                seconds++;
                handler.postDelayed(handlerTask, 1000);
        }
    };
    handlerTask.run();
}
```

Basically, what i would like to do is to update my gameTimeCount textview in the fragment class every second, from my GameController class. As i have understood its bad practice to do it with a static method like i am now. How else can i get a tick every second controlled from my GameController class? What would be a preferred and acceptable way to do this?

Comment: Is there some component (e.g. an Activity) which knows both the Fragment and the Controller?

Comment: @0X0nosugar oh ofcourse why i didnt think of that. Controller is a singleton so i can load the controller into the Activity which knows the fragment!

Comment: That's correct, and you can define an interface "TimeInfo" with a method "void updateTime(long)" which the Fragment has to implement. Then you pass an instance of that interface to the Controller. Don't forget to do null checks on everything and you'll be fine

Comment: @0X0nosugar could you post an example or a link which shows how to pass an instance of an interface?

Comment: Just look at all the methods taking a List (that's the interface) where you use e.g. an ArrayList but you might also use a LinkedList etc. If something implents an interface it promises you that there is a bundle of methods which will work as specified by the interface declaration